# Why my comparating sort from a array doesn't work?

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, comparator, junit5

Main class:

```
package simulator;

public class EmployeeSortByAnnualSalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{

    public EmployeeSortByAnnualSalaryComparator(){
        
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee anEmployeeSalary, Employee aSecondEmployeeSalary) {
        if(anEmployeeSalary.getSalary() < aSecondEmployeeSalary.getSalary()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(anEmployeeSalary.getSalary() == aSecondEmployeeSalary.getSalary()) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        
        }
    }

}
```

The interface should be like it is with the t.

When I try to sort name or the number, I see this error on the sort that my types are wrong:
`The method sort(List<T>, >Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments>(List<Employee>, EmployeeSortByAnnual Salary Comparator).`

Am I doing it the wrong way?
Edit: it is now fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Please paste the classes separated in a way that can be copied and pasted to test them.

Comment: `Collections.sort(this.ListOfEmployees, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));`

Comment: Friendly feedback: could you next time indicate in which step the error message belong to. In this case it is a compilation error. This would help to understand the type of issue that trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EmployeeSortByAnnualSalaryComparator` class is implementing your own `simulator.Comparator` interface, but it should implement the `java.util.Comparator` interface instead.

The `Collections.sort` method requires a comparator that implements the `java.util.Comparator` interface.